# Angular: property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, github, undefined

I have some problem with my angularjs-application. I have been doing some research on the web, but I can´t understand how to solve this issue. I'm a totally noobie when it comes to angular.

I have tried to build an application that parse information from GitHub, via API, to present user information in my table. However, after some processing to split the code into multiple js-files, it has brought problems.

Thank you in advance

**ng-app**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/index.html", {
            templateUrl: "index.html",
            controller: "searchForData"
        })
            .when("/github/:username", {
            templateUrl: "/templates/github.html",
            controller: "githubController"
        })
            .when("/tv", {
            templateUrl: "/templates/tv.html",
            controller: "searchForData"
        })
            .otherwise({redirectTo:"/index"});
    });
}());
```

**ng-controller**

```
    (function() {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    var githubController = function($scope, github, $routeParams){

        var onGithubComplete = function(data){
            $scope.user = data;
            github.getRepos($scope.user).then(onGitHubRepos, onError);
        };

        var onGitHubRepos = function(data){
            $scope.repos = data;
        };

        var onError = function(reason) {
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
        };

        $scope.username = $routeParams.username;
        github.getUser($scope.username).then(onGithubComplete, onError);
    };
    app.controller("githubController", githubController);
}());
```

**githubService.js**

```
    (function() {

    var github = function($http){

        var getUser = function(username){
            return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
            });
        };  

        var getRepos = function(user){
            $http.get(user.repos_url).then(function(response){
                    return response.data;
            });
        };

        return {
            getUser: getUser,
            getRepos: getRepos
        };
    };

    var module = angular.module("app");
    module.factory("github", github);
}());
```

**search.js**

```
    (function() {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    var searchForData = function($scope, $http, $location){

        var onError = function(reason) {
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
        };

        $scope.search = function(searchWord){
            $scope.array = searchWord.split(':');
            switch($scope.array[0]) {
                case 'github':
                    $location.path("/github/" + $scope.array[1]);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        };
    };
    app.controller("searchForData", searchForData);
}());
```

**ERROR**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at onGithubComplete (githubController.js:8)
>       at C (angular.js:10725)
>       at angular.js:10811
>       at h.$eval (angular.js:11726)
>       at h.$digest (angular.js:11554)
>       at h.$apply (angular.js:11832)
>       at f (angular.js:7774)
>       at K (angular.js:7947)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.y.onreadystatechange (angular.js:7903)

Comment: your `getRepos` function isn't returning the `$http` call.

Comment: Thank you! The question feels very ridiculous now when you gave me the answer. Thank you, made my day! Appreciate it!

Comment: sometimes the easiest mistakes are the hardest to find.  Don't feel bad, that's why we all spot each other. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `return` statement.

Note the difference:

```js
var getUser = function(username) {
  return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
};

var getRepos = function(user) {
  $http.get(user.repos_url).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your githubService -

```
    var getRepos = function(user){
        $http.get(user.repos_url).then(function(response){
                return response.data;
        });
    };
```

To

```
    var getRepos = function(user){
        return $http.get(user.repos_url);
    };
```

and then do `then` in your controller -

```
    var onGithubComplete = function(data){
        $scope.user = data;
        github.getRepos($scope.user).then(onGitHubRepos, onError);
    };
```